# How to parametrised sql query in apache-flink

Tags: apache-flink

I need to know can we parametrised apache-flink sql query like we do in java for sql query using `PreparedStatement`.

`Select * from emp where emp_id=?`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think currently Flink supports something like `PreparedStatement` in JDBC. Flink use-case is a little bit different than building web applications and I'm not really sure whether it needs a SQL Injection protection like applications that operate directly on the database.

I'm not sure what is Your use-case, but technically You can take a look at [this](https://openhms.sourceforge.io/sqlbuilder/) library, which offers a possibility to create the offline prepared statements.